# Implementing map using foldr in Emacs Lisp

Tags: haskell, emacs, elisp, fold

I'm starting to learn Emacs Lisp and as an exercise I'm trying to implement map using foldr. The code is the following:

```
(defun foldr (f z l)
   (if (null l)
       z
       (funcall f (car l)
                  (foldr f z
                           (cdr l)))))

(defun map (f l)
   (foldr (lambda (x z)
            (cons (funcall f x) z))
          nil
          l))
```

However, when I try to evaluate, for example,

```
(map (lambda (x) (+ x 1)) '(1 2 3 4 5))
```

in Emacs with eval-last-sexp (after evaluating both foldr and map), the result is the following:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-number-of-arguments (lambda (x z) (cons (funcall f x) z)) 1)
  (lambda (x z) (cons (funcall f x) z))(5)
  funcall((lambda (x z) (cons (funcall f x) z)) 5)
  (cons (funcall f x) z)
  (lambda (x z) (cons (funcall f x) z))(5 nil)
  funcall((lambda (x z) (cons (funcall f x) z)) 5 nil)
  (if (null l) z (funcall f (car l) (foldr f z (cdr l))))
  foldr((lambda (x z) (cons (funcall f x) z)) nil (5))
  (funcall f (car l) (foldr f z (cdr l)))
  (if (null l) z (funcall f (car l) (foldr f z (cdr l))))
  foldr((lambda (x z) (cons (funcall f x) z)) nil (4 5))
  (funcall f (car l) (foldr f z (cdr l)))
  (if (null l) z (funcall f (car l) (foldr f z (cdr l))))
  foldr((lambda (x z) (cons (funcall f x) z)) nil (3 4 5))
  (funcall f (car l) (foldr f z (cdr l)))
  (if (null l) z (funcall f (car l) (foldr f z (cdr l))))
  foldr((lambda (x z) (cons (funcall f x) z)) nil (2 3 4 5))
  (funcall f (car l) (foldr f z (cdr l)))
  (if (null l) z (funcall f (car l) (foldr f z (cdr l))))
  foldr((lambda (x z) (cons (funcall f x) z)) nil (1 2 3 4 5))
  map((lambda (x) (+ x 1)) (1 2 3 4 5))
  eval((map (function (lambda (x) (+ x 1))) (quote (1 2 3 4 5))) nil)
  eval-last-sexp-1(nil)
  #[257 "\204\303!\207  \303!\n)B\211A  =\204\211A\211@\207" [eval-expression-debug-on-error eval-last-sexp-fake-value debug-on-error eval-last-sexp-1] 4 2471606 "P"](nil)
  ad-Advice-eval-last-sexp(#[257 "\204\303!\207 \303!\n)B\211A  =\204\211A\211@\207" [eval-expression-debug-on-error eval-last-sexp-fake-value debug-on-error eval-last-sexp-1] 4 2471606 "P"] nil)
  apply(ad-Advice-eval-last-sexp #[257 "\204\303!\207   \303!\n)B\211A  =\204\211A\211@\207" [eval-expression-debug-on-error eval-last-sexp-fake-value debug-on-error eval-last-sexp-1] 4 2471606 "P"] nil)
  eval-last-sexp(nil)
  call-interactively(eval-last-sexp nil nil)
  command-execute(eval-last-sexp)
```

I don't understand why this doesn't work, when the following super similar implementation in Haskell works fine:

```
foldr f z l = if (null l)
              then z
              else f (head l) (foldr f z (tail l))

map f l = foldr (\ x z -> (:) (f x) z) [] l
```

So why aren't the Lisp and Haskell programs equivalent? What's the nature of the problem in the Lisp implementation, i.e., why isn't map working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(setq lexical-binding t)
```

`f` is a free variable in the lambda form you pass to `foldr`.

With lexical binding, your example works fine:

```
(map (lambda (x) (+ x 1)) '(1 2 3 4 5)) ; ==> (2 3 4 5 6)
```

Comment: Please don't recommend `(setq lexical-binding t)` since it doesn't really do what you want in general.  Instead he should add `-*- lexical-binding:t -*-` to the beginning of the file where you writes this code (and re-open that file to make that annotation take effect).

Comment: @Stefan: Yes, agreed, but there is no file here. That is, there is not necessarily a file. I took it that the code shown could be evaluated in other contexts - `*scratch*`, for example. The real point of the answer is that the OP code needs lexical binding.

Comment: sure, but don't give the rule as "use setq ..." since that's just a recipe for problems (including inducing a wrong mental model of how lexical-binding works).

Comment: You just need the lexical binding for the `f` variable. Hence this should work:  

``(defun mymap (f l)  
  (lexical-let ((f f))  
   (foldr (lambda (x z)  
            (cons (funcall f x) z))  
          nil  
          l)))``